# add css class to last column in each row in grid

Tags: jquery

I have a grid which has x rows and 6 columns. I want to add a class to the last column in each row.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're after here?  The question is about adding a class, the example is adding a class to the row...

Comment: Ok, scratch what I have in my update. I just want to add a class to the last td which is an image button so when I click on the image button I add an alert or what not based on the class. Does this make sense?

Comment: lol, your question title and your question aren't the same :)

Comment: @ Avinash -- sorry, I hope what I edit clearify it more.

Answer (score 1):

To get the 5th cell, if it's the last, use [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/), like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#myTable td:last-child").addClass("myClass");
});
```

To get the 5th no matter what, use the [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#myTable td:nth-child(5)").addClass("myClass");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

refer : **[:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)** , [**$.eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)   for information

```
$('td:last').addClass('addedClass');
```

or

```
var td = $('td');
td.eq(td.length - 1).addClass('addedClass');
```

Comment: This gets the absolute last cell, now the last in each row.

Comment: @nick Here the OP mentioned `I want to add a class to the last cell in the row `

Comment: @Avinash - Yes, exactly what I mean..."in the row" :) How is this per row?

Comment: @ Avinash and Nick -- what is wrong with what I have? And sorry guys, what I meant is "in each row".

Comment: @hersh - It's adding a class to the `<tr>`, which is what `this` is....what do you want it do to, add it to the `<div>`? Also you're appending a `<div>` to a `<tr>`, which isn't valid...

Comment: @nick you should comment on the OP's  question :), 'cause your comment is not related to this answer lol